# Bad response (400) with a WCF streaming service configured programmatically

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, streaming

this if my first attempt at using streaming for WCF, and I am struggling with the dreadful "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request" response.

The trace viewer says that this is a System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException with message "*There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details*." The inner exception type says "*The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.*"

Leaving everything else equal, if I switch to **buffered** mode on the client side, I am able to debug into the server code!

For some reason, I have to configure my service programmatically, as follows:

```
    public IUniverseFileService OpenProxy(string serviceUrl)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceUrl));

        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Name = "basicHttpStream";
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;

        var channelFactory = 
           new ChannelFactory<localhost.IUniverseFileService>(
              binding, 
              new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl));

        return channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }
```

While the server is configured as follows:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- BEHAVIORS -->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!-- SERVICES -->
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="Org.Acme.UniverseFileService">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  name="basicHttpStream" 
                  bindingConfiguration="httpLargeMessageStream"
                  contract="Org.Acme.RemoteCommand.Service.IUniverseFileService" /> 
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="" name="mexStream" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <!-- BINDINGS -->
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpLargeMessageStream" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                 transferMode="Streamed"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

I appreciate your help!

Stefano

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything started to work when I changed the transfer mode from `Streamed` to `StreamedResponse` as follows:

```
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse;
```

Still I don't understand why this works and `Streamed` does not, and why I am able to both send and receive a file stream from the server.

Comment: I had the same problem initially. In reality, all I need to stream back was the response anyway.

Comment: Worked for me as well. took me only 7h :x

Answer (score 5):

Streaming mode is not supported by ASP.NET development server. You need to deploy the service to IIS (or a WCF Service Application) to use Streaming mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add messageEncoding="Mtom" in bining tag.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.